# Free VM with management API that runs on windows?

Tags: vmware, virtual-machine, xen

Is anyone aware of a free (as in beer) VM that will run on a wide range of windows hosts (XP/Vista/7/etc), that comes with a full management API (at least the ability to create, monitor, start/stop and snapshot guest VMs) ?

I looked at VMPlayer, but its VIX API appears to be crippled for that product.
I looked at Xen, and it comes with a management API, but Xen only runs on Linux hosts.

thanks
Steve

Comment: Oracle's VirtualBox is my favourite https://www.virtualbox.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) I have ran that succesfully on both XP and 7, have not tried Vista